# BootstrapVue - Show b-modal after page loading

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I want to use the design on a modal in a new page but I dont want to click a button to show the modal. I got basic code like this:

```
<b-modal id="modalPopover" title="Modal with Popover" ok-only>
    <p>
      This
      <b-button v-b-popover="'Popover inside a modal!'" title="Popover">Button</b-button>
      triggers a popover on click.
    </p>
    <p>
      This <a href="#" v-b-tooltip title="Tooltip in a modal!">Link</a> will show a tooltip on
      hover.
    </p>
</b-modal>
```

i tried to add attributs like v-show="true", show="true" or @show but nothing worked for me. Does someone has a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in mounted hook using the component method `show()`, and accessing the modal by ref:

```
<b-modal 
    ref="mymodal"
    // other props...
></b-modal>
```

And:

```
mounted(){
    this.$refs.mymodal.show()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `visible` prop, by setting it to true and it will show up when mounted automatically.

```html
<b-modal visible>
  <!-- Content -->
</b-modal>
```